# Markdown header with custom numbering in jupyter notebook

Tags: header, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I would like to follow another documents numbering in my jupyter notebook.

e.g. I would like to start the first header at 3.2, the next 3.5 (because section 3.4 was not interesting) and so on.

```
# 3.2 section
# 3.5 section
```

So far, jupyter always starts at 1 and counts graclessly upward:

```
   1.1 section
   1.2 section
```

Can I hide that number?
Any ideas how to change this behaviour?